# When do I use which word for admission? 入場 vs. 入所

Tags: word-usage

I came across the both words in the title and wondered, if there is a general difference in their usage and/or meaning. In which cases do I use 入場, and when is it 入所?

Thank you!

Comment: When you enter a 場 like a stadium, you would use 入場. When you enter a 所 like 研究所, you would use 入所. I think it depends on the name of the place they are entering (野球場、劇場、刑務所、訓練所, etc）.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

入所 is usually reserved for entering a prison, a nursing home, etc. particularly (but not always) if the name of the place has a 「所」 in it's name, e.g. 研究所、刑務所、保育所 etc.

入場 is more common and used for admission to a park, a concert, etc. particularly (again, not always) if the name has a 「場」 like 野球場、キャンプ場, but also when someone makes an entrance (ゲストの入場、新郎新婦の入場）.

I think the main difference is time spent in the place being admitted to. Longer times (months, years) for 入所, shorter times (hours, days) for 入場.

p.s. I noticed that Halfway Dillitante made a comment that also mentions some of my examples while I was typing.

Answer (score 2):

According to the dictionary you use 入場  to enter places like 会場, 競技場, 式場, usually as a customer.
入所 is when you become a member or employee of an institution like a 研究所 (laboratory).

にゅうじょう【入場】会場・競技場・式場などにはいること。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/168262/meaning/m0u/入場/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/168262/meaning/m0u/%E5%85%A5%E5%A0%B4/)

にゅうしょ【入所】
１ 研究所など、所と名のつくところに所員としてはいること。
２ 刑務所にはいること。
３ 養護老人ホーム、児童養護施設、知的障害児施設、授産施設などの社会福祉施設に入って生活すること。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/168257/meaning/m0u/入所/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/168257/meaning/m0u/%E5%85%A5%E6%89%80/)